# Guid and NativeGuid throws a COMException

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to create new OU in the root of Active Directory, but it constantly throws an exception.Could there be because I'm tot an admin?

Link to screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ERLT64PIWrCoECzq0GGTdwMR1mQqln9w/view?usp=sharing

```
`
public void CreateGroup()
        {   
            DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ENCOTEC");
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dir);
            search.Filter = "(OU=IT System)";
            SearchResult it = search.FindOne();
            if (it == null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry newEntry = dir.Children.Add("OU=IT System", "organizationalUnit");
                dir.CommitChanges();
            }
`
```

Comment: What COMException?

Comment: @MickyD, just 'newEntry.Guid' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'. if I put my code in try-catch, code does not even reach a catch block.I can't even look at stack trace.You can see it in a screenshot

Comment: You're looking at an exception in the debug window. That's not actually part of your code, so no, a catch block won't catch that. Just ignore it. Does `CommitChanges()` throw an exception?